# MYSQL - How to merge 2 rows of related data into 1

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql and tried to research it but couldn't find any solution.  I have a table like this:

```
    | SW_Pair1        | SW_Pair2        | Pair1_VLAN1| Pair1_VLAN2| Pair2_VLAN1| Pair2_VLAN2| Inter | Mgmt| OSPF| Env | Domain|
    |-----------------|-----------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|-------|-----|-----|-----|-------|
    | Switch1.abc.com | Switch2.abc.com | VLAN-111   | VLAN-333   | Unknown    |  Unknown   |   47  | 24  | 0.1 | Dev | abc   |
    | Switch2.abc.com | Switch1.abc.com | VLAN-222   | VLAN-444   | Unknown    |  Unknown   |   47  | 24  | 0.1 | Dev | abc   |
    | Switch3.abc.com | Switch4.abc.com | VLAN-121   | VLAN-123   | Unknown    |  Unknown   |   47  | 24  | 0.1 | Dev | abc   |
    | Switch4.abc.com | Switch3.abc.com | VLAN-515   | VLAN-717   | Unknown    |  Unknown   |   47  | 24  | 0.1 | Dev | abc   |
    | Switch5.abc.com | Switch6.abc.com | VLAN-919   | VLAN-101   | Unknown    |  Unknown   |   47  | 24  | 0.1 | Dev | abc   |
    | Switch6.abc.com | Switch5.abc.com | VLAN-105   | VLAN-108   | Unknown    |  Unknown   |   47  | 24  | 0.1 | Dev | abc   |
    | Switch7.abc.com | Switch8.abc.com | VLAN-110   | VLAN-115   | Unknown    |  Unknown   |   47  | 24  | 0.1 | Dev | abc   |
    | Switch8.abc.com | Switch7.abc.com | VLAN-199   | VLAN-200   | Unknown    |  Unknown   |   47  | 24  | 0.1 | Dev | abc   |
```

Lets take first 2 rows as an example.
SW_Pair1 in row 1 ==  SW_Pair2 in row 2
SW_Pair1 in row 2 ==  SW_Pair2 in row 1

I put them in next row but they can be anywhere in database.  Now I would like to merge these 2 so that data in Pair1_VLAN1 and Pair1_VLAN2 in row 2 goes in Pair2_VLAN1 and Pair2_VLAN2 of row 1 and then row 2 disappears.  So, here is how the table should look after merge:

```
| SW_Pair1        | SW_Pair2        | Pair1_VLAN1| Pair1_VLAN2| Pair2_VLAN1| Pair2_VLAN2| Inter | Mgmt| OSPF| Env | Domain|
|-----------------|-----------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|-------|-----|-----|-----|-------|
| Switch1.abc.com | Switch2.abc.com | VLAN-111   | VLAN-333   | VLAN-222   |  VLAN-444  |   47  | 24  | 0.1 | Dev | abc   |
| Switch3.abc.com | Switch4.abc.com | VLAN-121   | VLAN-123   | VLAN-515   |  VLAN-717  |   47  | 24  | 0.1 | Dev | abc   |
```

and so on ..

I am using python 2.7 to push data to sql.

**Edit:**

I tried below query to add additional checks on DELETE but it failed:

```
UPDATE yourTable AS a
DELETE FROM yourTable AS b ON a.SW_Pair1 = b.SW_Pair2 AND a.SW_Pair2 = b.SW_Pair1
WHERE Pair2_VLAN1 IS Unknown;
```

Or better, can it SET the values of Pair1_VLAN1 and Pair1_VLAN2 rows of second switch after it moves it data to switch 1?  Maybe over-write the vlan to something like "MERGED".  I can then safely remove anything that has "MERGED" in Pair1_VLAN1 and Pair1_VLAN2.  I know it will only say that when it's data was successfully got moved to another row.

**EDIT2:**

nvm .. figured it out. See below:

```
UPDATE yourTable AS a
JOIN yourTable AS b ON a.SW_Pair1 = b.SW_Pair2 AND a.SW_Pair2 = b.SW_Pair1
SET a.Pair2_VLAN1 = b.Pair1_VLAN1,
    a.Pair2_VLAN2 = b.Pair1_VLAN2,
    b.Pair1_VLAN1 = "MERGED",   
    b.Pair1_VLAN2 = "MERGED
WHERE a.SW_Pair1 < a.SW_Pair2;
```

Comment: Do you just want to display the merged data or you actually want to store merged data in table?

Comment: save it and delete the other row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First update the first row in each pair with the data from the matching row:

```
UPDATE yourTable AS a
JOIN yourTable AS b ON a.SW_Pair1 = b.SW_Pair2 AND a.SW_Pair2 = b.SW_Pair1
SET a.Pair2_VLAN1 = b.Pair1_VLAN1,
    a.Pair2_VLAN2 = b.Pair1_VLAN2
WHERE a.SW_Pair1 < a.SW_Pair2;
```

The `WHERE` clause ensures that only one row in each pair (the one with the lower name in `SW_Pair1`) is updated.

Then delete the rows that weren't updated. They will still have `NULL` in the columns that were updated by the first query.

```
DELETE FROM yourTable
WHERE Pair2_VLAN1 IS NULL;
```

This assumes that there are matching rows for everything. If you need something safer, you'll need to do a join that checks that there's a matching row with the opposite names.

```
DELETE a FROM yourTable AS a
JOIN yourTable AS b ON a.SW_Pair1 = b.SW_Pair2 AND a.SW_Pair2 = b.SW_Pair1
WHERE a.Pair2_VLAN1 IS NULL
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Is there anyway to add some checks on DELETE so it does not delete Switches that do not have a pair?  I tried to formulate a query but got sql error.  Please see my edit.

Comment: You don't combine `UPDATE ` and `DELETE` in a single statement.

Comment: Worked like charm, thanks.  Last question, Is it possible to SET the values of Pair1_VLAN1 and Pair1_VLAN2 rows of second switch after it moves it data to switch 1? Maybe over-write the vlan to something like "MERGED".  Something like:    `SET a.`SEC_BB_A` = b.`PRI_BB_A`,
    a.`SEC_BB_B` = b.`PRI_BB_B`
    b.`PRI_BB_A` = MERGED
     b.`PRI_BB_B` = MERGED`

Comment: You mean instead of deleting those rows? Change the `DELETE` query to an `UPDATE` query that sets the fields to what you want.

Comment: What is `SEC_BB_A`? Those columns aren't shown in the question.

Comment: my bad Pair2_VLAN1| Pair2_VLAN2  are SEC_BB_A and SEC_BB_B. I was thinking it would be better on your first UPDATE query, after setting vlan, you also set vlan on the second switch that we would delete in next DELETE query.  Please see my edit 2.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how you can set it to `MERGED` in the same query.

Comment: I am getting " #1221 - Incorrect usage of UPDATE and ORDER BY" error.  Can you check my query in EDIT2?  I want to make sure it works.  I tested it and so far it is doing what it is supposed to.

Comment: Right, I can't use `ORDER BY` when you use `UPDATE` with a `JOIN`. So you'll have to do it as two queries as in my original answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there is a cleaner way to do this, but this is a hacky way I came up with.

```
select
a.sw_pair1,
a.sw_pair2,
a.pair1_vlan1,
a.pair2_vlan1 as pair1_vlan2,
b.pair1_vlan1 as pair2_vlan1,
b.pair2_vlan1 as pair2_vlan2

from TABLENAME a 
join TABLENAME b on a.sw_pair1 = b.sw_pair2
where cast(substring_index(substring_index(a.sw_pair1, '.abc.com', 1), 'Switch', -1) as unsigned) % 2 > 0
```

I'm using the modulo (% 2) to make sure we get the odd numbers in the first column only, therefore having the even numbers in column 2. I'd be curious to see if someone else can come up with a cleaner solution for that than I did. If so, that would help me with some of the things I do from time to time.

Comment: you may have a look at my answer in case you are curious about another approach. Hope it'll be helpful.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for commenting so I see that. Definitely helpful.

Comment: Glad to help. Kindly upvote in order to make it helpful to future visitors. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This method worked for me and seems simpler than the current answers. This gave your desired output from the sample data.

```
SELECT 
a.SW_Pair1, 
a.SW_Pair2, 
a.Pair1_VLAN1, 
a.Pair1_VLAN2, 
b.Pair1_VLAN1 as Pair2_VLAN1, 
b.Pair1_VLAN2 as Pair2_VLAN2 
FROM test as a , test as b
WHERE a.SW_Pair1 = b.SW_Pair2 AND a.SW_Pair2>b.SW_Pair2;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store the merged data into table, then @Barmar's solution will work perfectly.

But if you just want to display the data then following query will get the job done:

```
select least(t1.SW_Pair1,t1.SW_Pair2),greatest(t1.SW_Pair1,t1.SW_Pair2),
       t2.Pair1_VLAN1,t2.Pair1_VLAN2,
       t1.Pair1_VLAN1 as Pair2_VLAN1,t1.Pair1_VLAN2 as Pair2_VLAN2
from tablet1 as t1
inner join tablet2 as t2
on t2.SW_Pair1 = t1.SW_Pair2 and t2.SW_Pair2=t1.SW_Pair1
group by least(t1.SW_Pair11,t1.SW_Pair2),greatest(t1.SW_Pair1,t1.SW_Pair2);
```

Hope it helps!